# Unable to prevent browser back click after redirection

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm Using `Next.js` in my project. I am having payment option in my application., **Once I got redirected from the Payment gateway I want to stop user clicking browser back button**.

currently, If user click browser back buton it goes back to payment gateway.

I am using `next-routes`for routing, `redux` for state management.,

I tried to stop browser back navigation with this package ***disable-browser-back-navigation***, but the issue remains same.

can anyone help me on this.

Comment: You can't disable the browser back button. Web apps are not allowed to have that power. You should expire the payment session rather than trying to block the user from accessing the payment url. For example, they could copy and paste the url, so then even if you did disable the back button, the user would still be able to return to the page.